# jQuery .closest() returning multiple results

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a validation on my html form to highlight form inputs with the bootstrap class `has-error` in case the user enter wrong informations in my rails app.
I am using ajax with a custom `data` object which contains the error messages.
So far I've come up with this:

application.js

```
   jQuery.each(data.messages, function(i, val){
    $("label").val(i).closest("form-group").addClass("has-error");
  });
```

_account.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
 <%= account_form.label(:label, "Label") %>
 <%= account_form.text_field(:label, class: "form-control") %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <%= account_form.label(:iban, "Iban") %>
 <%= account_form.text_field(:iban, class: "form-control", maxlength: 29, data: {toggle: "tooltip"}) %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <%= account_form.label(:swift, "Swift") %>
 <%= account_form.number_field(:swift, class: "form-control", maxlength: 8, data: {toggle: "tooltip"}) %>
</div>
```

For example, `i` = `"swift"` and `val` = `"is blank"`, so if the user provides a label but forgets the other two, only `"swift"` and `"iban"` will be in `i`.

My problem is that for each loop the `.each` does, `.closest` returns all 3 divs so I can't manage to select a single div based on the label with `.closest`

Comment: It returns the three `.form-group` elements because you selected *all* the `label` elements (of which there is three)

Comment: What I meant is that each loop selects all 3 divs each time whereas each loop should only select its parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
 jQuery.each(data.messages, function(i, val){
  $("label:contains('"+i+"')").closest("form-group").addClass("has-error");
});
```

or this will match all text:-

```
jQuery.each(data.messages, function(i, val){
  var lbl=$('label').filter(function () {
       return $(this).text().toLowerCase()==i.toLowerCase();
   }).first();
  lbl.closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I isolated `$("label:contains('"+i+"')")`  to see and it doesn't select the labels accordingly, it doesn't select anything actually.

Comment: Your second code does work, I only had to to add a `.`to `.closest("form-group") because I forgot to put it myself in my question but it does seem to only add the has-error class to the corresponding divs, thanks.

Comment: @SORRROW sry my mistake yes you have to add `.` i.e class selector

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to select labels whose text is present in the `data.messages` object I think you can try

```
$('.form-group label').filter(function () {
    return !!data.messages[$(this).text().trim()];
}).closest("form-group").addClass("has-error");
```

Comment: I tried running your code but it doesn't do anything.